# Ionic 5 - native geoloc issues

Tags: geolocation, ionic5

So this is not a question, but after spending a fair amount of time figuring this one out, thought I'd just share and maybe save people some time,

Using the @ionic-native/geolocation with Ionic5, it seems to be better to use a previous version of the package, 
I personally used the `@ionic-native/geolocation@5.20.0` and seems to be working fine so far,

Strangely enough though, it works without declaring it as a provider, which doesn't raise any error,

Hope this helps, and any thoughts on this are welcome !

Comment: have you tried capacitor plugin ?

Comment: thanks for the answer, Lint. I had not looked into that yet, but reading the documentation now makes me think that this, vs Cordova,  might be the way to go indeed ! Thanks for the tip : )